github powershell checkout action fails intermitently with Authorization error: ***github.com//userbank/userrepo.git/info/lfs/objects/batch
Below is my complete simplistic testcase GitHub powershell windows workflow that fails for a particular repo and not for all repos.
name: Testcheckout - AD
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:

  setvars:
    runs-on:
      group: Shared2
      labels: myWINA3

    outputs:
      runner_name: ${{ runner.name }} 

    steps:

      - name: Checkout User Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          ref: "${{ github.ref }}"
          lfs: true
          fetch-depth: 1
          ssh-strict: false
          token: "${{ secrets.ARE_AUTOMATED_TOKEN }}"

Output Error:
Run actions/checkout@v4
  with:
    repository: userbank/userrepo
    ref: refs/heads/release/RELEASE_2024_OCT_24
    path: D:\A\3\_work\userrepo\userrepo\userrepo
    lfs: true
    fetch-depth: 1
    ssh-strict: false
    token: ***
    ssh-user: git
    persist-credentials: true
    clean: true
    sparse-checkout-cone-mode: true
    fetch-tags: false
    show-progress: true
    submodules: false
    set-safe-directory: true
  env:
    repodirexists: false
    devtoken: ***
Syncing repository: userbank/userrepo
Getting Git version info
Copying 'C:\Users\autobuild\.gitconfig' to 'D:\A\3\_work\_temp\7d866ea3-512c-44a6-92e5-d3bf9149ee80\.gitconfig'
Temporarily overriding HOME='D:\A\3\_work\_temp\7d866ea3-512c-44a6-92e5-d3bf9149ee80' before making global git config changes
Adding repository directory to the temporary git global config as a safe directory
"C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe" config --global --add safe.directory D:\A\3\_work\userrepo\userrepo\userrepo
"C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe" config --local --get remote.origin.url
https://github.com/userbank/userbank/userrepo.git
Deleting the contents of 'D:\A\3\_work\userrepo\userrepo\userrepo'
Initializing the repository
Disabling automatic garbage collection
Setting up auth
"C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe" lfs install --local
Updated Git hooks.
Git LFS initialized.
Fetching the repository
  "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe" -c protocol.version=2 fetch --no-tags --prune --no-recurse-submodules --depth=1 origin +refs/heads/release/RELEASE_2024_OCT_24:refs/remotes/origin/release/RELEASE_2024_OCT_24
  From https://github.com//userbank/userrepo
   * [new branch]      release/RELEASE_2024_OCT_24 -> origin/release/RELEASE_2024_OCT_24
Determining the checkout info
Fetching LFS objects
  "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe" lfs fetch origin refs/remotes/origin/release/RELEASE_2024_OCT_24
  fetch: Fetching reference refs/remotes/origin/release/RELEASE_2024_OCT_24
  batch response: Authorization error: ***github.com//userbank/userrepo.git/info/lfs/objects/batch
  Check that you have proper access to the repository
  Error: error: failed to fetch some objects from '***github.com//userbank/userrepo.git/info/lfs'
  The process 'C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe' failed with exit code 2

i tried implementing the below as a solution prior to the failing checkout action but it does not help.
- name: Github Clean Up Old Connections
  run: |
    Write-Host "Clean Up Old Connections"
    git config --global --unset-all http.https://github.com/.extraheader
    git config --global --unset-all core.sshCommand
    git lfs install
  shell: Powershell

git version on Windows is
"C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe" version
  git version 2.46.0.windows.1

The issue is overcome if I set  lfs: false in the checkout@v4 action.
The git version seems fairly new. Kindly suggest help implement a permanent fix.

Did you try adding dollar sign to false : $False?

@jdweng are you suggesting disabling lfs: false?  That works but I need lfs: true and not face the error.

@Ashar: Please include a consolidated workflow with all the relevant steps. Also, add the output of git lfs version. Are you using a self-hosted runner?

I don't use lfs much. Have you checked whether the CI credentials (repotoken) have access to the lfs storage ?

@LeGEC it does have access. Like i said the issue is intermitent so it works fine at times with no changes.

@Azeem git-lfs/3.3.0 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.19.3; git 77deabdf) is the git lfs version.

If it really is "intermittent", then it is not reproducible... To get help, I recommend to make it reproducible ;) When and how do you trigger the action in all your debugging/testing where it sometimes works and sometimes does not?

@stackprotector i have got a testcase that fails with the error reported.
Hoever, the same work for other repos and just fails for this single repo where i see the error.

So what is the difference between the working and failing repositories?
